# What happen to Orochimaru and his team after the war ended?

Tags: naruto

We all know Naruto has ended. But seriously, what happen to Orochimaru and his team, Suigetsu, Juugo, and Karin? What did Sasuke do to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was no mention of them. Not by manga nor by databook.

We might get a glimpse of them in The Last: Naruto the Movie, but we don't know, and likely never will. (Unless, of course, Kishimoto-sensei decides to reveal those details somehow).

Comment: Looking foward for the movie. in chap 700 sensei should have included about them

Comment: In the newest chapters of naruto gaiden he is shown to still do his research and still keeps getting bodies to live forever, Naruto (hokage) seems concerned but orochimaru says that he doesn't need to concern himself with it and naruto let it slide

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Anastasiya-Romanova, Sasuke left Taka and Orochimaru. Rest, character by character status is below:

## From [Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Gaiden:_The_Seventh_Hokage_and_the_Scarlet_Spring)

**[Karin](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Karin)**

After the war, Karin resumed her work for Orochimaru at one of his hideouts.

> She helped Sakura, by delivering her and Sasuke's daughter, Sarada at Orochimaru's hideout — as Sakura, while pregnant, had refused to leave Sasuke's side while he was traveling. She also became friends with Sakura, at some point.

**[Suigetsu & Jugo](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Suigetsu_H%C5%8Dzuki)**

Suigetsu and Jugo also joined Orochimaru's hideout. They even greeted the Naruto and next generation when they came to the hideout for

> Information about [Shin Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shin_Uchiha)

Suigetsu even increased the confusion of Sarada.

> Sarada requested for Suigetsu's assistance in checking whether Karin is her birth mother or not. Suigetsu found a strand of Karin's DNA in her desk (not knowing that it was Sarada's umbilical cord) and used it to run a test with that of Sarada's, which revealed a perfect match. Some time after Shin's defeat, Karin scolded Suigetsu for touching her belongings, explaining to him that he had used Sakura and Sarada's umbilical cord in the DNA test.

**[Kabuto](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kabuto_Yakushi)**

He runs Konoha Orphanage in the next generation era.

> He happily became a father to all remaining Shin clones and intended to name every single clone.

**[Orochimaru](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Orochimaru)**

Orochimaru even helped to break the [secret about Shin Uchiha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21513/who-is-the-person-in-the-akatsuki-cloak-in-chapter-702/22161#22161).

## From [Boruto: Naruto the Movie](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boruto:_Naruto_the_Movie)

Orochimaru has a cameo appearance in the film with one secret revelation

> Boruto and Sarada ask Mitsuki who his parents are and after he tells them it's Orochimaru, Sarada asks if he's the mother or the father. Mitsuki answers that either one is fine, while Boruto loudly asks who Orochimaru is. He's then shown standing on top of a house, looking at the three genin.

Answer (score 0):

According to the new release of [Naruto Gaiden manga chapter 7](http://www.mangahere.co/manga/naruto_gaiden_the_seventh_hokage/c007/8.html) (or Naruto manga chapter 707), Sasuke split up with team Taka and Orochimaru went back to his hideout with the rest of team Taka (Suigetsu, Juugo, and Karin).